# Extract text from PDF based on user's touch position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf, touch, text-parsing

How to extract the text from PDF file Using Objective C ?

Is there any code to parse the text position from the PDF file?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at FastPDFKit. It has text extraction as well as a number of other features. https://github.com/mobfarm/FastPdfKit